# Ethereum shape analysis

Tags: contract-verification

I am currently researching about the formal verification of smart contracts.
I am surprised that I did not manage to find a paper about the (shape) analysis of the storage of a contract.

Is there in the literature or in github a tool to perform shape analysis (on the storage and/or memory) of Ethereum?
If not, it is so, because this problem is not a concern or why nobody studied this problem?

Comment: There's this article about blockchain size https://dev.to/5chdn/the-ethereum-blockchain-size-will-not-exceed-1tb-anytime-soon-58a but I don't know if there's an automated way of analysis.

Answer (score 1):

We can see the application of a number of interesting formal verification tools and frameworks on Ethereum lately. In the event of rising attack vectors against the smart contract security model of Ethereum, formal verification has become a strong imperative. Initial efforts were based on Coq proof assistant. Nowadays we can see the adoption of K-framework and other powerful tools.

Ethereum 2.0 Beacon Chain has been formally verified using Dafny in the [PegaSysEng/eth2.0-dafny repository](https://github.com/PegaSysEng/eth2.0-dafny). Runtime Verification has done an excellent formal verification of Ethereum Casper CBC Proofs recently. It is available in the [following repository](https://github.com/runtimeverification/casper-cbc-proofs).  There is also an interesting formal verification of Ethereum in Lem in the [pirapira
/eth-isabelle](https://github.com/pirapira/eth-isabelle) repository. Lem is a language that can be translated into Coq, Isabelle/HOL, HOL4, OCaml, HTML and LaTeX. There is another interesting [EVM Semantics GitHub repository](https://github.com/kframework/evm-semantics) that applies the K-framework based formal verification of Ethereum Virtual Machine.